# EXTJS 2.2 EditorGridPanel doesn't show up sent data store

Tags: extjs

I'm working with EXTJS 2.2 I've already worked with an EditorGridPanel and when I load data store the grid doesn't load data sent. It just loads records in blank. I've checked the response JSON and the data sent is correct, what it doesn't load in my editorgridpanel. Here are some code:

```
var debeRecord = Ext.data.Record.create([
    {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'last', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'id', type: 'string'}
    ]);

    var DebeStore = new Ext.data.Store({          
        url: 'clases/TestStore.php',
        fields: ['Name','Last','Id'],
        reader:new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            reader: 'datos',
            totalProperty: 'total',
        },debeRecord),
        listeners:{
            beforeload:function(){
                DebeStore.baseParams.idtransferencia = this.selectednode;
            },
            scope:this
        }           
    });


var cmDebe = [
        {
         id:'col1',
         header:'No.Doc',
         width:380,
         editor: new Ext.form.TextField({allowBlank: true}),
         dataIndex:'Name'
         },
        {
         header:'Last',
         width:380,
         editor: new Ext.form.TextField({allowBlank: true}),
         dataIndex:'Last'
         },
         {
          header:'Id',
          width:380,
          editor: new Ext.form.TextField({allowBlank: true}),
          dataIndex:'Id'
          }
                     ];

//GridPanel del DEBE
     var debeGridPanel = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        frame:true,
        disabled:false,
        region:'center',
        id:'debeEditorGrid',
        split: true,
        autoScroll:true,
        title:'Listado de Transferencias (DEBE)',
        cls:'x-toolbar',
        tbar: [btnNewDebe, btnSaveDebe],
        //iconCls:'x-logo',
        autoExpandColumn:'col1',
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        store:DebeStore,
        sm:smDebe,
        loadMask:{
            msg :'Cargando Transferencias...'
        },
        columns: cmDebe,
        bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
            pageSize: 20,
            store: DebeStore,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Resultados de {0} - {1} de {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No hay resultados para mostrar."
        })
    });

//in the treepanel listeners click: function I load the store
click: function(node, e) {
                    this.selectednode = node.attributes['text'];
                    this.items.items[0].items.items[1].items.items[0].getStore().load({
                        callback: function(){
                            Ext.Msg.show({
                            title: 'Store Load Callback',
                            msg: 'store was loaded, data available for processing',
                            modal: false,
                            icon: Ext.Msg.INFO,
                            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                        });
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Does `dataIndex` match the record field names?

Comment: Can you share the json response you are working with?

Comment: Yes, the dataindex Match with record fields names

Comment: Here is the response [{"Name":"vb40052852     ","Last":"fdsfsdf   ","Id":"86952"},{"Name":"vb400528525458 ","Last":"askjdan   ","Id":"52148554"},{"Name":"vb4005285255454","Last":"sdfsdfsdf ","Id":"576425"},{"Name":"sdfsdfsdf      ","Last":"sdfsdfsdf ","Id":"4512365"}]